# Подсчет вхождений подстроки в строку

Tags: c, циклы

Нужно написать программу: строкой вводим 1 слагаемое, 2 слагаемое, строку для поиска. Программа переводит строку в число и считает сумму. Потом нужно посчитать кол-во совпадений в строке. Для этого полученный результат нужно опять перевести в строковую переменную. Пробовал написать через цикл, но программа всегда выдает 0.

Текст программы:

```
 char a[255], x[255], z[255], search[255];
    double a2, x2, z2;
    char*p = strstr(z, search);
    int k=0;
    printf("введите первое слагаемое ");
    gets(a);
    printf ("введите второе слагаемое ");
    gets(x);
    printf ("введите строку для поиска ");
    gets(search);
    a2=atof(a);
    x2=atof(x);
    z2=a2+x2;
    printf("результат %f", z2);
    sprintf (z, "%lf", z2);
    while(p != NULL)
    {
       p = strstr(p+1, search);
       k+=1;
    }
    printf("Количество совпадений%d",k);
    }
```

Comment: Весьма странная инициализация p. Что Вы хотели сказать третьей строкой?

     char*p = strstr(z, search);

Да, ещё, какие данные вводите (приведённая программа всё равно работать не будет, но задание хоть будет яснее)

Comment: да, очень странная инициализация в третьей строке. @MOHTuPOBKA, что там в массивах z и search ДО ТОГО, как в них что-то ввели? наверное, это строка должна быть где-то ниже, после того, как эти массивы получат свои значения.

В строке 14 должно быть %lf. Возможно, из-за этого неправильный результат на экране.

Comment: @MOHTuPOBKA, и, кстати, зачем плодить клоны вопросов? уже задавали вопрос [Перевод строковой переменной в числовую](http://hashcode.ru/questions/283732/c-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E). Не надо клонировать вопросы, просто поясните вашу ситуацию, тогда вас поймут и помогут :)